pythoon sqlite3 OperationError near from
I'm following this tutorial at minute 11:05
sqlite3 tutorial
and am getting an error
import sqlite3
from employee import Employee

conn = sqlite3.connect('employee.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT + FROM employees WHERE last='Schafer'")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "FROM": syntax error

I don't understand why.

Looks like a syntax error in the SQL query. You should have an Asterix ( * ) instead of a plus sign ( + ) in the query. It should read c.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last='Schafer'")
